# How can I work around the new Dart changes which prohibit implementing the same interface with different generics?

Tags: oop, dart, method-signature

My code is rather convoluted out of necessity. I have attempted to simplify the overall layout of the object system I'm working on in order to (hopefully) make it more understandable.

```
abstract class BaseType {}

abstract class MixinTypeA implements BaseType {}

abstract class MixinTypeB<T extends MixinTypeA> implements BaseType {
  Future<T> mixinMethod({bool argA = true,
      bool argB = true,
      bool argC = true}) =>
    someMethodCall()
}

abstract class BaseTypeA extends BaseType implements MixinTypeA {
  // declares a constructor
  BaseTypeA();
}

abstract class BaseTypeB extends BaseType implements MixinTypeB {
  // declares a constructor
  BaseTypeB();
}

abstract class TypeA extends BaseTypeA {}

class TypeB extends BaseTypeB with MixinTypeB<TypeA> {}
```

In this case, TypeB will generate an error.  This is because it attempts to mixin `MixinTypeB<TypeA>`.  Because TypeB already extends `BaseTypeB` which implements `MixinTypeB` with the inferred `<MixinTypeA>` generic, the `MixinTypeB` interface is implemented twice with two different (although related by inheritance) interfaces: `TypeA` and `MixinTypeA`.

Essentially, the `T` generic exists to keep my code DRY.  The method example in `MixinTypeB` is one of the various potential methods that the class could have with a specific type signature of `T`.  I don't know how to get around the new restriction without compromising the inheritance structure of this type system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, the most common solution to this is to thread the generics through the hierarchy to make the types line up.  For this specific example, the following code works.

```
abstract class BaseType {}

abstract class MixinTypeA implements BaseType {}

abstract class MixinTypeB<T extends MixinTypeA> implements BaseType {
  Future<T> mixinMethod({bool argA = true,
      bool argB = true,
    bool argC = true}) => null;
}

abstract class BaseTypeA extends BaseType implements MixinTypeA {
  // declares a constructor
  BaseTypeA();
}

abstract class BaseTypeB<T extends MixinTypeA> extends BaseType implements MixinTypeB<T>{
  // declares a constructor
  BaseTypeB();
}

abstract class TypeA extends BaseTypeA {}

class TypeB extends BaseTypeB<TypeA> with MixinTypeB<TypeA> {}
```

If you don't need to be able to mix together `BaseTypeB` with any other instantiations of `MixinTypeB`, then the following simpler approach can work as well:

```
abstract class BaseType {}

abstract class MixinTypeA implements BaseType {}

abstract class MixinTypeB<T extends MixinTypeA> implements BaseType {
  Future<T> mixinMethod({bool argA = true,
      bool argB = true,
    bool argC = true}) => null;
}

abstract class BaseTypeA extends BaseType implements MixinTypeA {
  // declares a constructor
  BaseTypeA();
}

abstract class BaseTypeB extends BaseType implements MixinTypeB<TypeA>{
  // declares a constructor
  BaseTypeB();
}

abstract class TypeA extends BaseTypeA {}

class TypeB extends BaseTypeB with MixinTypeB<TypeA> {}
```

Comment: First of all, I'd like to thank you for the suggestion.  Your initial assumption is correct--I need to be able to use BaseTypeB for multiple classes.  However, this solution, "threading", feels a bit strange to me.  For example, one caveat to the this solution is that it will appear strangely in dartdocs, with a generic that is useless to the user being visible.  Logically, the solution makes perfect sense.  But in practice, to me, it feels like more of a work-around than a proper solution.  However, as I understand it, it may be the only solution.  I'm interested to hear your thoughts!

Comment: I don't think I really have enough context on your original code to say whether this is a workaround or the right thing to do.  :)  Based on this example, it's odd to me that you would make `MixinTypeB` generic instead of just making `mixinMethod` return `Future<MixinTypeA>`, but then turn around and use `MixinTypeB` without a generic argument.  The only reason I can see for saying that `BaseTypeB` implements `MixinTypeB` is so that you can use it as an interface which has `mixinMethod` right?  But why do you not care to have the precise generic type on that interface?

Comment: The goal of using generics in this case is mostly in order to get `mixinMethod` to have the proper type signature.  Essentially, `TypeA` and `TypeB` are associated.  The inherited `mixinMethod` for `TypeB` should return `TypeA`.  In addition, if I was to create a subclass for TypeA (and thus also TypeB), the `SubtypeB` would have to have its `mixinMethod` return `SubtypeA`.  I hope this makes sense! :)

Comment: Yes, it makes sense that `MixinTypeB` would be generic, what I'm not entirely clear on is why the original code made `BaseTypeB` implement `MixinTypeB<dynamic>` instead of either not implementing it at all (since you mix it into `TypeB` anyway), or else implementing it at a specific type.  Not saying it's not reasonable, just that that was the bit I didn't understand.

Comment: More generally, there are definitely uses for implementing the same interface with different generic arguments, and it's entirely possible that this code is one of them.  For Dart 2, we felt that these use cases were rare enough to be worth having to work around it when they arise, since there are other benefits to not supporting this.  There is a proposal for supporting inference of type arguments that might reduce the boilerplate in client code for this: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/mixin-inference.md .

Comment: `BaseTypeB` implements `MixinTypeB` because it requires some properties of `MixinTypeB` (this is not clear from the simplification I provided).  It seems that at the moment, generic threading is my only option.  I look forward to the new mixin system, and I hope that it will be able to address cases like this. Thanks!